# Django Model not recognising model fields using Serialiser Class Generic Views

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to get a list of templates from a Django model, but I always get an error.
Below is the error whenever I attempt to retrieve the list of job templates. I get this error because it doesn't recognise the field template_name.

> AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `template_name` on serializer `ListJobTemplateSerializer`.
> | The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Job` instance.                                   | Original exception text was: 'Job' object has no attribute 'template_name'.

Job Model:

```
class Job (Dates, ID):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, validators=[name_validation])
    is_remote = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    company = models.ForeignKey(to="companies.company", related_name="%(class)s", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Template Model:

```
class JobTemplate(Dates, ID):
    template_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    jobs = models.ForeignKey(to="jobs.Job", related_name="%(class)s", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    objects = BulkUpdateOrCreateQuerySet.as_manager()

  class Meta:
      db_table = 'job_template'

  def __str__(self):
      return name


 class ListJobTemplateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   """List all templates of a job."""
   job_title = serializers.CharField(source="name")

   class Meta:
     model = JobTemplate
     fields = ["id", "job_title", "template_name"]
```

Comment: It looks like the serializer you use works on a `Job` model, not the `JobTemplate` model, so likely a different one than you show here.

Comment: But I get id field from the job template model correctly but it fails for template_name

Comment: Your question lacks a [mre], but from the error it seems you use the `ListJobTemplateSerializer` for a `Job` instance... The serializer is for the `JobTemplate` model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you must be making some mistakes in your views. There's no problem with your model and with your serializer, there are fine. As there's not enough information provided the possible problem lies in the queryset, as your queryset is fetching Job object, not JobTemplate object you have to revamp your queryset for fetching JobTemplate.

Reference Document that can help you with queryset: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/

Comment: Yes the problem is with my query set I have figured it out, thank you!